# Selenium run very slow

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys, time

def main():
    url = sys.argv[1]
    sku_t = 'skuId='
    sku = url[url.index(sku_t)+len(sku_t):]

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.headless = True
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    start_time = time.time()
    driver.get(url)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" %(time.time() - start_time))

    css_param = 'button.add-to-cart-button[data-sku-id="'+sku+'"]'
    add_to_cart_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_param)
    print(add_to_cart_btn.text)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to write a python script to check BestBuy inventory (to checkout later if possible). It takes around 90s to finish. I am not sure if there is something wrong with how I use selenium or is there anything I can do to improve the performance. Below is the log. Thank you in advance

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62866/devtools/browser/fb0dfd00-0aee-4bec-9e6e-8411e18593d6
[0130/193519.329:INFO:CONSOLE(127)] "bby_privacy: getServerComponent", source: https://nexus.ensighten.com/bestbuy/privacy_init/Bootstrap.js (127)
[0130/193519.660:INFO:CONSOLE(143)] "getServerComponent suppressed", source: https://nexus.ensighten.com/bestbuy/privacy_prod/Bootstrap.js (143)
[0130/193529.699:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to script at 'https://assets.bbystatic.com/shop/master-ad/dist/client/client-978b7e491e0889e92a05356af57308d2.mjs' from origin 'https://www.bestbuy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/xfx-amd-radeon-rx-6800-16gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-gaming-graphics-card-black/6442077.p?skuId=6442077 (0)
[0130/193535.454:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught (in promise) t: request to /button-state/api/v5/button-state?skus=6442077&conditions=&storeId=&destinationZipCode=&context=pdp&consolidated=false&source=buttonView&xboxAllAccess=false timed out after 5000ms", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/fulfillment/fulfillment-summary/dist/client/client-51a75235b1a89815b2bb615b099f1639.js (1)
[0130/193539.609:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to script at 'https://assets.bbystatic.com/shop/display-ad/dist/client/client-72a4443f23ae7927233dfaa3239ddc89.mjs' from origin 'https://www.bestbuy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/xfx-amd-radeon-rx-6800-16gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-gaming-graphics-card-black/6442077.p?skuId=6442077 (0)
[0130/193539.791:INFO:CONSOLE(718)] "LibEmbeddedComponentRenderer: Embedded component queries can only contain strings, numbers, booleans or CsiVar objects with non-empty name strings.
The query param object key "locale" contains unsupported value:  undefined", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/gvp-287c65223d1c49e3d4181939b6c98ef4.min.js (718)
[0130/193540.756:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "firing initData from parent", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/analytics-dotcom/chunks/tagIframe-6b64f0d171878bd514b6.js (8)
[0130/193540.758:INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "starting gate fired!", source: https://nexus.ensighten.com/bestbuy/tagframe_dev/code/d0f9a4f369cc4aace811197f11e3a9b9.js?conditionId0=1195706 (6)
[0130/193541.920:INFO:CONSOLE(14)] "canary version not set", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/@ds/unified-chat/dist/javascript/unified-chat-init-f92615d5.js (14)
[0130/193558.181:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Failed to pass the CSI variable to account libTypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/shop/header/dist/client/client-current-6040b166d0f69756a5b4d62f14255057.mjs (1)
[0130/193558.593:INFO:CONSOLE(14)] "Dispatching button is sold out for  - 233--null", source: https://assets.bbystatic.com/fulfillment/add-to-cart-button/dist/client/client-807bf7e58728fff64dda829e243a6d4e.js (14)
[0130/193558.627:INFO:CONSOLE(14)] "Dispatching button is sold out for  - 233-77001-null", source: https://assets.bbystatic.com/fulfillment/add-to-cart-button/dist/client/client-807bf7e58728fff64dda829e243a6d4e.js (14)
[0130/193603.621:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught (in promise) t: request to /fulfillment/ispu/api/ispu/v2 timed out after 5000ms", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/fulfillment/fulfillment-summary/dist/client/client-51a75235b1a89815b2bb615b099f1639.js (1)
[0130/193603.655:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught (in promise) t: request to /fulfillment/shipping/api/v1/fulfillment/sku;skuId=6442077;postalCode=77001;deliveryDateOption=EARLIEST_AVAILABLE_DATE timed out after 5000ms", source: https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/fulfillment/fulfillment-summary/dist/client/client-51a75235b1a89815b2bb615b099f1639.js (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are API's available specifically for [Best Buy](https://bestbuyapis.github.io/api-documentation/). If you don't want to use an API, try including these chrome_options

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
```

If these don't work, try to run the script without headless mode.
Additionally, you don't actually need `selenium` to scrape the availability and prices, as these are stored in the page source. So you can alternatively use `requests` to check for the availability of an item and only invoke `selenium` if an item is available and you want to add it to your cart.